# web deployment package (.zip file) not created in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-publishing

I am trying to create a deployment package in Visual Studio 2013. I have specified that the package should be placed at C:\Deployment\bin\WebSite.zip - the absolutely simplest location. All the project files build but the publish fails with this error:

```
Transformed Web.config using C:\Services\IdentityServer\Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2\src\OnPremise\WebSite\Web.Siloed.config into obj\Siloed\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
Auto ConnectionString Transformed Areas\Admin\Views\Web.config into obj\Siloed\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Areas\Admin\Views\Web.config.
Auto ConnectionString Transformed Views\Web.config into obj\Siloed\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Views\Web.config.
Auto ConnectionString Transformed obj\Siloed\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config into obj\Siloed\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Web.config.
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
obj\Siloed\Package\PackageTmp.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2584,5): Error : Copying file ..\..\..\Deployment\bin\um.zip to obj\Siloed\Package\PackageTmp\.ebextensions\um.zip failed. Could not find a part of the path '..\..\..\Deployment\bin\um.zip'.
```

I have no idea where this path '......\Deployment\bin\um.zip' is coming from. I specified that the deployment package should be created at C:\Deployment\bin\WebSite.zip, not um.zip.

So, I checked out C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2584,5) and the code looks like this:

```
<!--Force Copy Of all file to the $(WPPAllFilesInSingleFolder) if needed-->
<CopyPipelineFiles PipelineItems="@(FilesForPackagingFromProject)"
                       SourceDirectory="$(WebPublishPipelineProjectDirectory)"
                       TargetDirectory="$(WPPAllFilesInSingleFolder)"
                       SkipMetadataExcludeTrueItems="True"
                       UpdateItemSpec="True"
                       DeleteItemsMarkAsExcludeTrue ="True"
                   Condition="'@(FilesForPackagingFromProject)' != ''">
  <Output TaskParameter="ResultPipelineItems" ItemName="_FilesForPackagingFromProjectTempory"/>
</CopyPipelineFile>
```

I have tried editing the "PipelineItems" and "SourceDirectory" and have even hardcoded them. But the same message, **"Could not find part of the path...."**, is being displayed every time I run the Publishing. The  **"Could not find part of the path...."** points to the new paths I specified in "PipelineItems" and "SourceDirectory. The .zip file never seems to get created anywhere. I have seached my entire computer for um.zip and WebSite.zip with not luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am completely out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this um.zip is somehow part of build but it is not getting created. Anyway, I was lucky enough to find a previous deployment package that was generated and I just manually built the new deployment package based off the old one. Deployed fine so I guess that is how I will proceed.